# Android - Return to calling Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Newbie Question from an iPhone developer.

I have called the startActivity(intent) and the new activity loads. How do I go 'back' to the calling activity once a button is pushed. 'Popping' the activity off the stack basically.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you had created the new Activity with [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) you just need to call [`finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29).  If you had spawned the new Activity by calling [`startActivityForResults`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) then you need to call [`setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) and then [`finish`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) in order to pass back data to the [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method of the prior Activity.

Comment: One more thing, The requestCode is for identifying which call it was. (in cases here you have more than 1 `startActivityForResults`)

Answer (score 6):

Call `finish()` on your newly loaded activity. This is assuming you didn't call `finish()` on your previous activity (in which case you could always restart it).

Answer (score 2):

Calling finish() closes that activity and gets back to the previous screen(or Activity which called that) , or exits the app if that is the main activity which launched app.