# How to control activity stack/clear activity stack in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have an application that goes as follows (Home being the launch activity):

```
D
C
B
A
Home
```

My flow goes as follows:

The user starts activity `A` from `Home`, which flows to `B` and `C`.  When the user leaves activity `C`, I want `A`, `B`, and `C` to be destroyed.  That is, if the user presses `BACK` in activity `D`, it goes back to `Home`.

The user must be able to control program flow normally through activity`A`, `B`, and `C`.  So if they press the back button in activity`C`, it goes back to activity `B`.

I've looked at Intent flags such as `CLEAR_TOP` and `NEW_TASK`, but none of them seem to do what I want them to.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME)? It requires API level 11 though :(

for API level <11, this can be done:

when starting activity B and C, use startActivityForResult(). When starting activity D, do this:

```
startActivity(D);
setResult(KILL_YOURSELF); //KILL_YOURSELF is some arbitrary int that you use to identify that the other activities should exit
finish(); //finish the activity
```

This will kill activity C. Then in activity A and B, override onActivityResult like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == KILL_YOURSELF) {
            setResult(KILL_YOURSELF);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Thus activity B will finish, which in turn will trigger onActivityResult in A, so it will also finish.

Comment: I'm programming for API  7+, unfortunately.  Good try, though!

Comment: Well, since that flag seem to do what you are looking for, I would conclude that you cant get what you want with a flag. You can do it manually though, by some somewhat ugly code. I.e. finish activity A,B and C with finish() as you launch D :)

Comment: Yes, but how do I access A,B,C from D other than creating a static array (which would be horrifying memory-wise)?

Comment: When launching from C, finish C. Make sure that C was started with startActivityForResult(), so that B:s method onActivityResult() is triggered. Thus you can finish B, and  then A in the same fashion :) This is a tad ugly, but I see no better option.

Comment: I thought of a recursive call... could you provide a lightweight example?  I haven't used onActivityResult() for anything but retrieving contacts and logging users in.

Comment: I edited my answer, try it and see if it works out for you :)

Comment: I'm using MVC methodology, so I don't have direct access to overrides (not sure why, I'm working on a codebase someone before me wrote...), but this looks correct, and I'll give it a try after some refactoring.  Marking it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Love the constant name KILL_YOURSELF - it got a chuckle.

Answer (score 0):

Simply [intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/back-functionality-on-button-click-in-android) the Back Button in Activity D, and upon intercepting the Back Button, head over to the Home Activity. You may / maynot want to finish 'D' activity as you are heading over to the Home Activity.