# Programmatically go back to the previous fragment in the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

Say I have an activity that has fragments added programmatically:

```
private void animateToFragment(Fragment newFragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, tag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

What is the best way to return to the previous fragment that was visible?

I found [Trigger back-button functionality on button click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/back-functionality-on-button-click-in-android) but I'm thinking simulating a back key event isn't the right way to go about it (and I can't get it to work either):

```
dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

Calling `finish()` just closes the activity which I'm not interested in.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Look at the `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` methods (there are several to choose from)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();` did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Where would I put this method though? In my tab listener?

Comment: without seeing the code, it's hard to say... but it should go in the section of code that is executed when you want to "close" the current fragment and return to the previous fragment.

Comment: what about getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: @alicanbatur yes you need to use addTOBackStack().

Comment: What if we want to go to a fragment second or third previous. I visited fragments A->B->C->D and I want to go back to A or B from D?

Comment: use popBackStack("A", flags)  (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate(int, int))

Comment: Don't forget to add "addToBackStack("tag")" in your code.
"fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).addToBackStack("tag").commit();"

if you write addToBackStack(null) , it will handle it by itself but if you give a tag , you should handle it manually.

Comment: Not seems works. in 2016, into setNavigationOnClickListener not works.

Comment: `popBackStackImmediate` is slower than `popBackStack` in order to avoid performance issues use `popBackStack` where ever possible.

Comment: the answer is now deprecated, you should use `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()`

Comment: This sends me back to the first fragment.

Comment: in kotlin you should use `supportFragmentManager().popBackStack()`

Comment: Note that if you're using navigation, this will work in getting you back but if you then try to navigate to the fragment that you popped, you'll encounter an error about not being able to navigate from the current destination. Instead, use `findNavController().navigateUp()`.

Answer (score 141):

To elaborate on the other answers provided, this is my solution (placed in an Activity):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

Comment: and why is that happening. In fragment example http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html they are not overiding onbackpressed event and yet they are able to backstack fragment. 

I have used  trasaction.addToBackStack(null); but nothing happens. 

Can you explain why ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain you should probably ask a new question if you want help with this. It's a little hard to see what's going on without looking at more code.

Comment: In my case I had to do `fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1` in order to call the activity back when there is only the first fragment in the stack.

Comment: Android already do this for you: _"When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action (such as removing a fragment if the transaction added it)."_ [(Source)](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Answer (score 38):

When we are updating/add the fragments,

Should Include the `.addToBackStack()`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(detailFragment, "detail") // Add this transaction to the back stack (name is an optional name for this back stack state, or null).
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

After that if we give the `getFragments.popBackStackImmediate()` will return true if we add/update the fragments, and move back to the current screen.

Answer (score 27):

**Android Navigation architecture component.**

The following code works for me:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```

Comment: This method comes in handy when you are using a custom designed toolbar. Works like a charm.

Comment: If you are using the navController I think you have to use this method - I first tried the fragment manager (the answer above) and got a crash when later trying to navigate using navController.

Answer (score 18):

These answers does not work if i don't have addToBackStack() added to my fragment transaction but, you can use:

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

from your any fragment to go back one step;

Comment: `requireActivity().onBackPressed()` for Kotlin

Answer (score 10):

Add those line to your onBackPressed() Method. popBackStackImmediate() method will get you back to the previous fragment if you have any fragment on back stack
`

```
if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
     getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

`

Answer (score 6):

This solution works perfectly for bottom bar based fragment navigation when you want to close the app when back pressed in primary fragment.

On the other hand when you are opening the secondary fragment (fragment in fragment) which is defined as "DetailedPizza" in my code it will return the previous state of primary fragment. Cheers !

Inside activities on back pressed put this:

```
Fragment home = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DetailedPizza");

if (home instanceof FragmentDetailedPizza && home.isVisible()) {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
} else {
    //Primary fragment
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

And launch the other fragment like this:

```
Fragment someFragment = new FragmentDetailedPizza();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_body, someFragment, "DetailedPizza");
transaction.addToBackStack("DetailedPizza");
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 5):

**Kotlin Answer**

1. First, call *Fragment Manager*.
2. After, to use *onBackPressed()*
   method.

Coding in Android Studio 4.0 with Kotlin:

```
fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
```

Comment: also try `activity?.onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 3):

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
```

OR

```
 getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically go back to the previous fragment using following code.

```
if ( getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) 
{
          getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          return;
}
super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 2):

To make that fragment come again, just add that fragment to backstack which you want to come on back pressed, Eg:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack("SignupFragment");
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

In the above case, I am opening `LoginFragment` when `Button button` is pressed, right now the user is in `SignupFragment`. So if `addToBackStack(TAG)` is called, where `TAG = "SignupFragment"`, then when back button is pressed in `LoginFragment`, we come back to `SignUpFragment`.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I think, TAG doesn't affect, it even maybe null.

Answer (score 2):

By adding `fragment_tran.addToBackStack(null)` on last fragment, I am able to do come back on last fragment.

*adding new fragment*:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.changepass).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new ChangePassword());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Following **Kotlin** code useful to me

*1. Added in Simple Activity class with multiple fragments used*

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "=============onBackPressed - Popping backstack====")
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "=============onBackPressed called because nothing on backstack====")
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

*2. Added in **BottomNavigationView** Activity class with multiple fragments used*

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    Log.e(TAG, "=============onBackPressed")
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    when (navController.currentDestination!!.id) {
        R.id.navigation_comments, R.id.navigation_my_posts -> {
            menuItemPosition = 0
            navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_home)
            Log.i(TAG, "=============onBackPressed - Popping backstack with First fragment ====")
        }
        else -> {
            Log.i(TAG, "=============onBackPressed called because nothing on backstack====")
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking or the same idea, and in the meantime i came up with own, which I believe is not that bad and works if with ViewPager.

So what I did, is to override the onBackPressed method in the parent activity that holds the viewPager, and set it to always go back minus 1 position until it reaches the first fragment, then closes the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()>0){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.close();
    }
}

private void close(){
    this.finish();
}
```

This might have a downfalls, like it only goes back one way left each time, so it might not work great if there are tabs and you switch positions with fragments skipped, ( going from 0 to 2, and then pressing back would put you on 1, instead of 0)

For my case tho, with 2 fragments in viewPager without tabs, it does the job nicely.

Comment: Similar question is already answered. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment myFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        if (myFragment != null && myFragment instanceof StepOneFragment) {
            finish();
        } else {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```