# On home button click(in appbar/toolbar) from next activity, I need same fragment on main activity(which was there before going to next activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment on my main activity which gets loaded on click of item from nav drawer and on click of a list item from the fragment(main screen) I navigate to another activity. If I press the device back button I get my fragment screen(as expected) but if I use a tool bar and enable the the home button by saying

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I get my main activity content which was prior to selecting an item from drawer. I have set parent of next activity as the main activity but I need the fragment loaded when i go back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically go back to the previous fragment in the backstack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack)

Comment: @miva2 not exactly what i was looking for but yes can be useful in future. I got solution for my problem. will post in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my problem I found a solution. on click of the home button in the toolbar I killed my activity using `finish()` method and it worked just as i wanted. Hope it helps the needy.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        finish();       //kill subActivity so as to get same screen which was before going to subActivity
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

You need to add this `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
along with  `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: I had tried this but my mainActivity had view X then view Y and then from view Y i started another activity on click of a list item. so when i used `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` i was able to go back but view X was loaded and instead i wanted view Y. Check my answer, I got the fix.