# Android - update toolbar title in activity while handle back navigation with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Activity hosted slide menu with fragments , when user click at any item in slidemenu fragment is opened , I need to handle back navigation

when user click at item in list I call this method to display proper fragment

```
public void SelectItem(int position) {

        Fragment _fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                _fragment = Test_Home.newInstance();
                break;

            case 1:
                _fragment = Diseases_Fragment.newInstance();
                break;

          ........

            case 8:
                Logout();
                break;

            default:
               break;

        }

        if (_fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_content, _fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
             // set title , this textview in toolbar 
            _frag_title.setText(nav_items[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
```

this method to handle back button

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

my onCreate method

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_view);
            Toolbar _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

           setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
           getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           _frag_title = (TextView) _toolbar.findViewById(R.id.frag_title);
    }
```

in fact it work just fine , but my problem is displayed fragment show old title dont show new title

is there way call my method `_frag_title.setText(nav_items[position]);`

my problem not in back navigation , my problem how to update toolbar title in navigation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically go back to the previous fragment in the backstack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack)

Comment: my problem not in back navigation , I provide working code , my problem in update tool bar title

Comment: you are using different title for different fragment. and you want to to change that title on toolbar whenever change fragment? m i right?

Comment: yea this right I will change title now

Comment: ok then check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34020202/1168654

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to change title of tool bar whenever change fragment you have to do below way.

1. must have to use fragment with TAG name or by ID, i will show you how to use that using TAG name(you can also use by id in that case you have to change my code).

to use by TAG, you have to add fragment TAG, whenever you add fragment in layout, **let's add fragment by TAG**

```
Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.MainFrameLayout,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
    .addToBackStack("YOUR_SOURCE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

---

after do above way, in **onBackPressed** check which fragment on you are, using below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG");
        if (fragment instanceof FragmentA) {
            // add your code to change title of toolbar
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

Comment: What if using `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.MainFrameLayout,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
    .addToBackStack("YOUR_SOURCE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit(); `? Becuase if I use `add` method instead of `replace` it doesn't call `onResume`

Answer (score 1):

here is a piece of my code after resolve this issue

```
public void SelectItem(int position) {
        Fragment _fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                _fragment = Test_Home.newInstance();
                break;

            case 1:
                _fragment = Diseases_Fragment.newInstance();
                break;

          ........
          .....

            case 8:
                Logout();
                break;

            default:
               break;

        }

        if (_fragment != null) {
         // I add tag when I add fragment to BackStack
          String backStackName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_content, fragment, "TARGET_TAG")
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(backStackName)
                .commit();
        _frag_title.setText(nav_items[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } 
       }
```

I add BackStackChangedListener on `onCreate` method

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_view);

        ......
        ....

        .
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.view_content);
                if (f != null) {
                    updateTitleAndDrawer(f);
                }
            }
        });
}

   private void updateTitleAndDrawer(Fragment f) {
        String name = f.getClass().getName();
        if (name != null) {
            ChangeTitle(name);
        }
    }
 private void ChangeTitle(String fragmentName) {
        if (fragmentName.equals(Test_Home.class.getName())) {
            _frag_title.setText(nav_items[0]);
        } else if (fragmentName.equals(Diseases_Fragment.class.getName())) {
            _frag_title.setText(nav_items[1]);
        } else if (fragmentName.equals(Questions_Fragment.class.getName())) {
            _frag_title.setText(nav_items[2]);

       .......... 
       .......
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle this on resume of each oh your Fragment to specify the title when it comes back to the fragment.

Currently what happens is, you are setting the title in `onCreate` or somewhere when it actually creates the `fragment`, But since the `tool bar` is not something that resides inside `Activity` (Not in the `Fragment`) You have to make changes to that specifically. Best place is `onResume` method of the fragment.

*So try setting up the `TextView` in your `onResume` of your `Fragment`*

Comment: my problem not in setting title , the problem when user click back tool bar keep old title not update to display fragment , let consider it show fragment two with title two , when user click back it show fragment one but the title still two

Comment: @MinaFawzy were you able to figure out the issue?

Comment: I think I will find way to do that, but your answer is wrong

Comment: What part is wrong, is the onResume not called on back button pressed?

Comment: I am using textview inside toolbar

Comment: can you check  if the onResume of Fragment is called on back button pressed?