# How to prevent application closed on pressing device back button?

Tags: android

I am developing application in which I have three fragment A,B,C, when I press on some button in A it navigate to b Thats fine ,and when I press device back button application closes instead of going to A,How can I prevent this problem .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Overriding onBackPressed()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337536/android-overriding-onbackpressed)

Comment: Because clicking "Back" button triggers your holder activity to close rather move back to fragment. To handle fragments implement backstack mechanism using fragment's life cycle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically go back to the previous fragment in the backstack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack)

Answer (score 2):

// Your Main Activity
// Override OnBackPressed Event Which as below

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager()
                .getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

            super.onBackPressed();

        } else {

            UIUtils.showAlertDialog(this, getString(R.string.app_name), "Are you sure want to Exit App?", false);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the activity's onBackPressed() function according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

You should override onBackPressed() method. There you can choose what action to do when this happens. If you still want to finish the activity in some cases, you can call finish() method.

Answer (score 0):

**Please add**

```
addToBackStack(null);
```

> to your FragmentTransaction object if you not added when replacing or
>   adding fragments.

it will autamatically maintain backstacks on Backpress.

Hope it will help you !