# Single activity multiple fragments navigation issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main activity which hosts multiple fragments. I have a base fragment class which is inherited by all other fragments.

I have a main home screen fragment which have some buttons to display sub fragments. Now inside the sub fragment i have some buttons which displays its sub fragments. Now when i click back button i should go back to the previous fragment from which i have opened the current fragment but its always taking me to home screen fragment.

This is how i have written the main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener, View.OnClickListener {


private Context context;
public HashMap<String, Stack<BaseFragment>> mStacks;

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

private TextView toolbarTitle,toolbar_signout;
public String mCurrentTab;

private ActionBar actionBar;
public BaseFragment fragment = null;
public String title;

private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    toolbarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbar_signout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_signout);
    toolbar_signout.setOnClickListener(this);
  //  toolbarSettings = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_settings);

    mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<BaseFragment>>();
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_HOME, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_INCIDENTS, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_LICENSE, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_CREATE, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE_DETAILS, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_CHECKLIST_WAREHOUSE, new Stack<BaseFragment>());
    mStacks.put(MyConstants.TAB_UPLOAD_FILES, new Stack<BaseFragment>());

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

enter code here
    displayView(0);
}


@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}

private void displayView(int position) {

    title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_HOME;
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            pushFragments(mCurrentTab, fragment, false, true);
            title = getString(R.string.Incidents);
            break;
        case 1:
            mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_INCIDENTS;
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            fragment = new IncidentFragment();
            pushFragments(mCurrentTab, fragment, false, true);
            title = getString(R.string.Incidents);
            break;

        case 2:
            mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_LICENSE;
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            fragment = new LicensesFragment();
            pushFragments(mCurrentTab, fragment, false, true);
            title = getString(R.string.Licences);
            break;
        case 3:
            mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE;
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
            pushFragments(mCurrentTab, fragment, false, true);
            title = getString(R.string.ScheduleVisits);
            break;
        case 4:
            mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_CREATE;
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).clear();
            fragment = new CreateScheduleFragment();
            pushFragments(mCurrentTab, fragment, false, true);
            title = getString(R.string.SchedulenewVisits);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}


public void pushFragments(String tag, BaseFragment fragment, boolean shouldAnimate, boolean shouldAdd) {
    if (shouldAdd)
        mStacks.get(tag).push(fragment);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    /*
     * if(shouldAnimate) ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
     * R.anim.slide_out_left);
     */
    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);

    ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean temp = true;
    if (temp) {
        temp = false;

        if (mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 1) {
            if (mCurrentTab.equals(MyConstants.TAB_HOME)) {
            } else {
                displayView(0);
            }

        } else {
            int stackSize = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size();
            BaseFragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).get(stackSize - 1);
            //popFragments();
            if (fragment.onBackPressed())
                popFragments();
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing.. fragment already handled back button press.
    }
    temp = true;
}



public void popFragments() {
    /*
     * Select the second last fragment in current tab's stack.. which will
     * be shown after the fragment transaction given below
     */
    Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).elementAt(
            mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() - 1);

    /* pop current fragment from stack.. */
    mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).pop();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    // ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

Now in my home screen button clicks i am calling the fragments in this way

```
 layout_schedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View view) {
                                               mActivity.mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE;
                                               mActivity.mStacks.get(mActivity.mCurrentTab).clear();
                                               mActivity.fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                                               mActivity.pushFragments(mActivity.mCurrentTab, mActivity.fragment, false, true);
                                               mActivity.title = getString(R.string.ScheduleVisits);
                                           }
                                       }
    );

    layout_newincident.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onClick(View view) {

                                                  mActivity.mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_CREATE;
                                                  mActivity.mStacks.get(mActivity.mCurrentTab).clear();
                                                  mActivity.fragment = new CreateScheduleFragment();
                                                  mActivity.pushFragments(mActivity.mCurrentTab, mActivity.fragment, false, true);
                                                  mActivity.title = getString(R.string.create_schedule);
                                              }
                                          }

    );
```

Now from Inside the ScheduleFragment() fragment i have a button which opens a new fragment

```
 activity.mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE_DETAILS;
    activity.fragment = new FragmentScheduleDetails();
    activity.pushFragments(activity.mCurrentTab, activity.fragment, false, true);
    activity.title = activity.getString(R.string.schedule_details);


 public boolean onBackPressed(){

    return true;
}
```

if i click back button from this FragmentScheduleDetails() fragment it is taking me back to the home screen but i am trying to go to the ScheduleFragment().

Please correct me. I am definitely going in a wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863743/6672577

Comment: Is there any navigation logic inside `fragment.onBackPressed()`? If yes, add it to the post as well.

Comment: @nikis it has nothing just iam returning true onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

If you want flow as A->B->c->
then on backpressed A->B

so you should write

> ft.addToBackStack(null);

in pushFragment() method before

> ft.commit();

Answer (score 0):

This is working exactly as you wrote. You can split navigation logic in simple steps.

Step 1. You click on `layout_schedule` which opens `ScheduleFragment`. What is the state after this action? `mCurrentTab  = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE` and `mStack.get(MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE).size() == 1`

Step 2. You click and open `FragmentScheduleDetails`. What is the state after this action? `mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE_DETAILS` and `mStack.get(MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE).size() == 1`

Step 3. You click Back button. At this point you fall into the branch `mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() == 1`, because `mCurrentTab = MyConstants.TAB_SCHEDULE_DETAILS`. And in this branch you call `displayView(0)`, which effectively shows home screen.

I guess you wanted to implement `Instagram-like` navigation. In this case you should use only tags of root views as keys for `mStacks` and operate on some field called `mCurrentRoot`. Or better to use the lib like this https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav

Comment: displayView(0) will be called only once because i am working with single activity. And the displayView(0) is written under OnCreate() method.

Comment: @ShahidAleem it is called at least twice: in `onCreate` and also during your back navigation, check step #3.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your fragments to stack with `ft.addToBackStack("fragment-name")` for handling back button.
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal

Comment: I guess OP wants his own navigation logic, Instagram-like, which is not possible with naive `addToBackStack` calls.