# How to make sure that back button for settings fragment goes to the launching fragment with aac

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

So I have an issue with AAC navigation. I have multiple fragments in one activity. I inflate the menu options in MainActivity so that each fragment has access to the menu item which opens the settings. The problem is that each time I press the back button on a fragment, it does not go back to the fragment that launched it. It goes back to the original fragment.
Is there a way to make sure this behavior is assured? Thanks

Comment: Did you calling fragment by menu item Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling fragment by menu item id then do it in your activity like below.It will solve your problem.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item,navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

And your menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

MenuCategory = "secondary" will not pop out back stack to start destination.

Comment: I'll be damned but this works!!. Thanks. Let me mark it as the correct answer

Comment: me too...i didn't believe it happens.

Comment: It does work. I am using Java though to implement the AAC navigation component. The idea is the same though. Once again, thanks. Back to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FragmentManager and add the fragment to the BackStack.

I recommend taking a look at this post: [Go back to the previous fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863572/programmatically-go-back-to-the-previous-fragment-in-the-backstack)

Comment: If he uses Navigation AAC then he shouldn't need to touch the FragmentManager directly

Comment: How should I do it @EpicPandaForce? Because the way suggested by P. Vera is for the older method of simply using a navigation drawer and not aac navigation

Comment: Guys, check out the answer I have marked as correct above. It is brilliant