# Android Back to previous fragment by popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have 3 fragments: Home, A and B. Home and A are in mobile navigation menu.

User goes from A to B and then press back button. The issue that if I use `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` onCreateView of fragment A is calling and I have duplicating of content.

But if I use `getActivity().onBackPressed();` it goes to Home fragment instead of A.

How to display fragment A by clicking back button without refreshing the view?

Here is how I make transaction from A to B

```
 CertificateItemFragment certificateItemFragment = new CertificateItemFragment(item);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, certificateItemFragment).addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17369359/6587502

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know some premise before using FragmentManager.

1. in `Activity` there is **FragmentManager** and we should call it with `getSupportFragmentManager()`, `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated.
2. in `Fragment` there are **multiple FragmentManagers** called `ParentFragmentManager` and `ChildFragmentManager`, the final `FragmentManager` which is deprecated too. And `ParentFragmentManager` will be same as **Activity's FragmentManager**
3. `getActivity().onBackPressed()` will pull out fragment if any stack exists in **Activity's FragmentManager**
4. `fragmentManager.popBackStack()` will pull out fragment if any stack exists in **Activity's or Fragment's** FragmentManager rely on who calls

---

Base on above points

(1) If You want to hold fragments in `Activity`, you should call `getSupportFragmentManager()` in **Activity**, and call `getParentManager()` in **Fragment**, then `onBackPressed()` will pull out the fragment you last add to stack.

(2) If you want to hold fragments in a Fragment and Separated from Activity, you should call `getChildFragmentManager()` in Fragment, then `activity.onBackPressed()` will pull out the fragment which in Activity's fragment stack and ignore other fragments in Fragment's fragment stack.

---

For question will be same as case (1), and if you dont want re-create fragment, you should use `add()` instead of `replace()`

**in Fragment A**

```
CertificateItemFragment certificateItemFragment = new CertificateItemFragment(item);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, certificateItemFragment).addToBackStack(CertificateItemFragment.TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

now `onBackPressed()` will backstack from **CertificateItemFragment** to **Pre-Fragment**

Answer (score 1):

In normal case navigation item list menu open fragment which are replace to each other but when we move inside of any item as like in your case move from fragment A to B,
In this case normally we use another activity on which create fragment.

If you do't want to use activity then, you just need to add fragment.

try below code that may help you

```
CertificateItemFragment certificateItemFragment = new CertificateItemFragment(item);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, certificateItemFragment).addToBackStack(CertificateItemFragment.TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```