# finishActivity() does not work unless BACK is pressed after selecting the submit button

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent

I have a generic tutorial-based application that passes user information to a second activity. On the second activity, the user opts whether to "agree" via a CheckBox. When the user clicks the submit button, they are suppose to return to the previous activity, with a SnackBar confirming whether they checked the agree CheckBox.

The problem is, the submit button on the second activity does not appear to function correctly. It uses the `finishActivity(int)` method, but nothing happens.

---

What greatly confuses me is that if I then select the back button on my phone, I am returned to my first activity. On top of that, it appears to still pass the information set with `setResult()`, and not only correctly returns the expected `requestCode`, but also correctly returns the `intent` and determines whether the CheckBox was set to `enabled==true` or not.

This does not happen, if I do not click the submit button, first. If I press the back button on the second activity, without first pressing the submit button, the application closes.

---

The submit button on my `MainActivity` initiates the `MoveToConfirmationActivity` method:

```
/** Moves us to the second activity, the Confirmation Activity */
public void MoveToConfirmationActivity(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(REQUEST_CONFIRMATION, REQUEST_CONFIRMATION_INT);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONFIRMATION_INT);
}
```

I have also overridden the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` as follows:

```
/** Runs when this activity is returned to by another activity */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CONFIRMATION_INT) {
        // Retrieve the accepted flag from the Confirm Activity, with the default as false.
        boolean accepted = data.getBooleanExtra(ConfirmActivity.AGREE, false);

        if(accepted) {
            SnackbarToast(getString(R.string.agree));
        }
        else {
            SnackbarToast(getString(R.string.disagree));
        }
    }
}
```

For point of clarity, I do not have `requestCode` set anywhere outside of `onActivityResult()` for it to misinterpret its own value.

---

The submit button on my `ConfirmActivity` initiates the `StartReturnToMainActivity` method:

```
/** Creates an intent to pass the checkbox value, and returns us to MainActivity. */
public void StartReturnToMainActivity(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AGREE, mAgreeCheckbox.isChecked());

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finishActivity(mMainRequestInt);
}
```

In hindsight, I realise that it has always been doing this. While the submit button has never worked, I have always been able to use Back to go back to the previous activity, after selecting submit. It was only after including `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);` that my first activity has been reacting to the desired selection. The answer from an alternate question suggested that this was a requirement.

I can confirm that `setResult` and `finishActivity` still apply the logic of passing the `resultCode`, `requestCode` and `intent` back into the first activity. I have worked out that any 'changes' I make after selecting submit will not move across with the back button, unless I select submit again.

---

I have gone through the tutorials on the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/index.html), and they have helped considerably in leading up to this point; however, in respect to the code on the side of `ConfirmActivity`, all I can find is the implication that I should already know what I am doing. I believe [the main tutorial I followed](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) intended the second activity to come from an external source.

I found a lot of useful information, here on StackExchange; but across the many similar questions, the final answer seems to be that `finishActivity(int)` should ultimately *always* send me back to the previous activity.

[Thanks to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/trigger-back-button-functionality-on-button-click-in-android), I have worked out that I can "code in" the press of the back button immediately after my `finishActivity()` with `onBackPressed()`. With this consideration, everything appears to work as intended. However, I consider this a less-than-desirable hack. I would much rather have an understanding of why it is not working as expected, and how I should properly return to the previous activity.

***Is this the correct implementation of `finishActivity(int)`? Why do I still need to hit the Back button on my phone for it to work, and how do I fix this?***

Comment: have you tried just (finish();)

Comment: @Tasos, I have. `finish()` outright closes the app

Comment: Strange -- That will happen if you are on the Main-activity.  (finish();)  just finishes the current activity so the previous Activity appears again.

Comment: @Tasos, I am also using it on my main activity on an exit button. It still closes from the main activity, including if I've returned there from the second activity.

Comment: There is no way (ACTIVITY B with finish();) would Kill the (MAIN ACTIVITY)

Comment: Are you sure its an Activity where ( the user opts whether to "agree" via a CheckBox) and not a DIALOG box??

Comment: @Tasos, interestingly enough, it does not appear to *kill* it. I have logs on all of my lifecycle overrides. While the intentional "kill" button runs `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`; implementing it in the second activity only appears to run its `onPause` method.

Comment: It does not appear to be a dialog box.. I was told to use `class ConfirmActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener`

Comment: @Tasos, well that sucks. It appears `finish()` *did* solve this problem. After I turned off my computer for a day, and did another refresh of Android Studio :/

Comment: If you care to provide a short answer pointing out *why* we use *finish* and not *finishActivity*, I'll be sure to mark your answer as correct, seeing a you technically gave me the right answer from the very get go.

Comment: dont worry its ok, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by ***Tasos***, using `finish()` instead of `finishActivityint()` *did* actually fix my problem. To an extent..

It seems this solution only made a difference *after* I shut down my computer, turned it back on, *and* performed a rebuild of my project.

I believe this *might* be *somewhat* new, given that it contradicts the highly-voted answer I previously found, here on StackOverflow. That said, if anyone else has a similar "silly problem" like this;

1. Try turning it on and off again
2. Do a rebuild of the project

I have previously had weird issues that fixed themselves upon rebuilding; but never an issue that solved itself only after a *complete* system restart.