# onBackPress in Service

Tags: java, android

I need to somehow press the back button, but do it programmatically, without pressing the physical button, or play **finish()**, only in another application.

I found this: [Trigger back-button functionality on button click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/trigger-back-button-functionality-on-button-click-in-android), but this reproduces the click from activity, and I need from service

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Error, writes that there is no such method

Comment: Explaining what you're trying to do a little more might help.

Comment: @Jak I have a service in which clicks are performed on a certain area, after clicks I need to return to the previous page