# onBackPress for Service

Tags: java, android

I need to somehow press the back button, but do it programmatically, without pressing the physical button, or play **finish()**, only in another application.

I found this: [Trigger back-button functionality on button click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649508/trigger-back-button-functionality-on-button-click-in-android), but this reproduces the click from activity, and I need from service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way for handling back press using only `Service`, but you can fake this click using [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) (and `performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)` method call), there is no other way...

Comment: Thanks you. You save me)